# C - strlen() seems to return a minumum of 6

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50, strlen

The following is part of an exercise of the CS50 course. The full problem is described here:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/2/substitution/

In short: on the command line you provide a 26 long array of letters as an argument and those letters will be used to 'encrypt' a string that is prompted for during runtime called plaintext.

The plaintext array is then looped over and their ascii integer value (somewhat simplified) is used to index into the '26 letter key' that was provided as an command line argument, thus 'encrypting' the initial plaintext string (ptxt) and storing it in a new ciphertext string (ctxt).

**The problem** I'm having is that for input where plaintext is *shorter* than 6 - the strlen() function I use to store the length of ptxt in 'n' seems to return 6. So if i type just the letter 'a' at the plaintext prompt - n seems to be set to 6.

Following examples:

> $ ./substitution YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO
>
> plaintext: a
>
> ciphertext: y.G[
>
> ciphertext is 6 long

the expected output would just be 'y' , but clearly something is going out of bounds - the length should not be 6 but just 1.
The thing that drives me nuts is - if you *uncomment* the printf statement after initializing 'n', then the code suddenly works and you get the following:

> $ ./substitution YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO
>
> plaintext: a
>
> plaintext is 1 long
>
> ciphertext: y
>
> ciphertext is 1 long

**What am I missing here?
And how is it that a printf call somehow remedies this issue?**

Driving me nuts :)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_letter(string array);
char encrypt(string key, char c);

//Command Line input a key to 'encrypt' some plaintext inputted at runtime
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // if there are NOT 2 arguments OR the first argument is NOT just letters OR is not 26 letters
    if (argc != 2 || !is_letter(argv[1]) || strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key (where key must be 26 letters)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // prompt user for a plaintext string, store the length in n and initialize a ciphertext string with same length
    string ptxt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int n = strlen(ptxt);
    //printf("plaintext is %i long\n", n); //this is here to correct n (try commenting out this line and see what happens for ptxt < 6)
    char ctxt[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ctxt[i] = encrypt(argv[1], ptxt[i]);
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ctxt);
    printf("ciphertext is %i long\n", (int) strlen(ctxt));
    return 0;
}


// function that checks whether command line argument is all letters
bool is_letter(string array)
{
    int n = strlen(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(array[i])) //loop over string - if any char is not a letter - return false
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; //reaching this means all chars in the string are a letter - return true
}

//function that takes a key and a char and returns the "encrypted" char
char encrypt(string key, char c)
{
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        int n = 0;
        char letter = 0;
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            n = c - 65;
            letter = key[n];
            return toupper(letter);
        }
        else
        {
            n = c - 97;
            letter = key[n];
            return tolower(letter);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to terminate `ctxt` with `'\0'`, that's all. Unrelated to `strlen`.

Comment: You also need `char ctxt[n+1];` to allow room for the null byte.

Comment: How are you expecting `printf` to know how many characters to print? How are you expecting `strlen` to know the length of the array? When things aren't doing what you expect, the first thing to look at is *why* you expected different behavior and whether your expectation was reasonable.

Comment: @Barmar, Tried that already - doesn't change anything.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - How would I manually set the nul terminator? syntactically I mean.

Comment: `ctxt[n] = '\0';`

Comment: @Peter I said *also* -- it goes along with adding the null terminator.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -  To be fair: I honestly don't fully know how I expect strlen to know the length of an array. It's a library function that should do 'just that' right, return the length of a string? I haven't looked into the actual code behind the function.

I use that function to set get the length of ptxt, store that in n, then initialze ctxt with size n. which printf statement are you referring to? I expect ctxt to be as long as ptxt because i use the length the loop over ptxt to fill in ctxt.

Comment: @Barmar 
Sorry, misunderstood. Still not 100% sure if I understand you correctly.
however,  using   char ctxt[n];    ctxt[n] = '\0';   works  - so i require both lines and that does seem to remedy the issue. Is this always required after you initialize a new array?  (it wasn't taught like that in the course)

Comment: if you don't understand how it works, you need to go back to your textbook/tutorial and reread the chapter on strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "string" in C. "Strings" in C are really arrays of bytes, `char *`. Arrays in C do not know how long they are, there are no built in [bounds checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking). You either need to know their size, or have a terminator. "Strings" are terminated by a 0 known as a "null byte" and usually represented as `\0`.

`strlen` reads the bytes until it sees a null byte. If there's no null byte, `strlen` will happily walk off the end of the array into garbage memory until it happens to see a null byte or the OS prevents the program from going outside its memory bounds, a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

```
// A basic strlen() implementation.
size_t my_strlen(const char *string) {
    size_t len;

    // no body, just counting until it sees a null byte.
    for( len = 0; string[len] != '\0'; len++ );
    
    return len;
}
```

(IMO CS50 does a disservice by trying to hide this while you're learning C. There's a long tradition of trying to treat C as if it was not C. The bare metal, hot rod, no guard rails nature of C cannot be hidden piecemeal. You either end up with a mess or a new language. If you want strings, use C++ or a fully realized library like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.68/).)

When making a new string byte by byte, you must terminate it. And it must have an extra byte to store the 0.

```
    // Allocate an extra byte for the terminating null.
    // At this point ctxt contains garbage.
    char ctxt[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ctxt[i] = encrypt(argv[1], ptxt[i]);
    }

    // Terminate the string.
    ctxt[n] = '\0';
```

> And how is it that a printf call somehow remedies this issue?

When you allocate memory like `char ctxt[n+1]`, it is *uninitialized*. It is not automatically zeroed out. It contains whatever trash was in that memory. You could get lucky and get all zeros. It could contain other strings. It could contain what looks like random garbage.

Adding a `printf` just before you allocate `ctxt` changes ever so slightly what memory block is allocated to `ctxt`. `printf` must also allocate memory, so `ctxt` might get a slightly different memory block that happens to start with zeros. `ctxt` might get a block of memory that printf allocated, zeroed, and deallocated. Since memory is a global resource, a change in one part of the program can reveal or hide a memory bug in another part of the program.

Tools such as [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) and [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) can help find these subtle mistakes.

Comment: You might also touch on arrays in C. Unlike other languages, an array doesn't track its own length, it is just a block of memory and programmer must ensure nothing goes beyond the end of it.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey That's supposed to be CS50's job. ;) Good suggestion, I've added it in.

Comment: Thanks Schwern, that is very helpful indeed. It surely wasn't explicitly mentioned/ taught that we have to terminate the strings ourselves, but it makes sense and it works. I'm still unsure on the following though: Can you explain why for strings longer than 6 characters this seems to work fine (without manually terminating ctxt beforehand) but for shorter strings it doesn't?

Comment: working for > 6 characters is pure chance.  Your program is simple enough you were hitting unused stack memory pretty quick (only 6 bytes), but that's just a quirk of the loader

Comment: @Peter Likely because ctxt's unallocated garbage starts with a few characters of trash then a  block of zeros. Consider `ctxt = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'z', 'y', 'x', '\0'}` If you only overwrite the first few characters with 123 ctxt is `{'1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'z', 'y', 'x', '\0'}` or "123def". If you overwrite with 123456 ctxt is `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'z', 'y', 'x', '\0'}` or "123456". If you overwrite with 123456789 ctxt is `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'z', 'y', 'x', '\0'}` or "123456789zyx".

Comment: In hindsight - I think at this point in the CS50 course they expect you to only use strllen() on your plaintext input so you can use that length value, only to loop your logic and then actually use printf to output your answer during that loop - so not first storing it in a new array and then printing that in its entirety. (Also, I dabbled in Python prior to this - clearly ' my Python is showing' - as this low level management is very interesting, but also very new to me :)
Memory management seems to be 2 lessons further in the course.

Comment: Thanks everyone, terminating arrays (amongst others) clearly is what I was missing - very helpful.

Comment: @Schwern wait, i have one more question :). I noticed that if I use `char ctxt[n];` and then `ctxt[n] = '\0';` the code still works - but wouldn't that logically imply that I'm '1 size' short in ctxt to fully copy ptxt AND terminate ctxt? Wouldn't I I have to set the size of ctxt to `char ctxt[n+1];` . Or am I just being lucky again?

Comment: @Peter Yes, you're just being lucky. The OS will stop the program from stepping outside the program's allocated memory, but C will not stop the program from stepping outside a variable's allocated memory. There are no runtime bounds checks. If you stray outside the lines, changes to ctxt might overwrite another variable's memory. Or the extra memory might be allocated to another variable which can then overwrite ctxt's. The tools I mentioned at the end can catch these mistakes. ctxt is just the memory address (a pointer) of the start of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, much appreciated!